# Requerid application for use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in Plesk

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, plesk

I have a site that want to open word and use it. I use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` for it. it work in local but in server(plesk) i get error.

```
 CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

I want to install office in server. What software && version should be installed ?

I use `OpenXml` but it doesn't can save word in pdf format. and don't open word with it.